# C# AES decryption always end in 10 bytes messy code.

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

I have a text file "toEnc.txt" (file size is 485b) to encrypt and decrypt.

After encryption, the "byte[] enc_data" 's length increases to 496b.
But I've set "enc.Padding = PaddingMode.None;"

And after decryption, no matter what the text content is , "testout.txt" always have 10 bytes of messy code in the end.

I also tried .zip file. The encrypted file length increased too and the decrypted file was corrupted after decryption (probably because of the weird messy code in the end of zip file ).

Here is my code:

```
       private async Task RunEncryption()
       {
           String data;
           using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("toEnc.txt"))
           {
              data = sr.ReadToEnd();
           }
           byte[] enc_data = await Program.myEncrypt(data);

            await RunDecrypt(enc_data);   //to test if decryption works
      }

    static async Task<byte[]> myEncrypt(string toEncStr)
    {
        byte[] encrypted;
        using (Aes enc = Aes.Create())
        {
            Aes encaes = Aes.Create();
            encaes.Key = enc.Key;
            encaes.IV = enc.IV;

            Program.Key = enc.Key;
            Program.IV = enc.IV;

            try
            {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream("key.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                fs.Write(Key, 0, Key.Length);
                fs.Write(IV, 0, IV.Length);
                fs.Close();
            }
            catch ( Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Encryption failed!{0}.", e.Message);
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

            enc.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

            ICryptoTransform encryptor = encaes.CreateEncryptor(encaes.Key, encaes.IV);

            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        swEncrypt.Write(toEncStr);
                    }
                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
        return encrypted;
    }

    private async Task RunDecrypt(byte[] inbytes)
    {
        try
        {
            String write_data = await myDecrypt(inbytes);
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("testout.txt", true))
            {
                sw.Write(write_data);
                sw.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
    async Task<String> myDecrypt(byte[] toDecBytes)
    {
        try
        {
            String decrypted;
            using (Aes dec = Aes.Create())
            {
                byte[] Key = new byte[dec.Key.Length];
                byte[] IV = new byte[dec.IV.Length];
                FileStream fsread = new FileStream("key.txt", FileMode.Open);
                fsread.Read(Key, 0, Key.Length);
                fsread.Read(IV, 0, IV.Length);
                fsread.Close();

                dec.Key = Key;
                dec.IV = IV;

                dec.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = dec.CreateDecryptor(dec.Key, dec.IV);
                using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(toDecBytes))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        {
                            decrypted = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                            //decrypted = srDecrypt.Read(  , 0, );
                            return decrypted;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Decryption failed! {0}.", e.Message);
            return @"null";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using 2 `Aes` variables - `enc` and `encaes`? You are setting the  `Padding` on `enc` variable, but then using `encaes` for encoding.

Comment: Eh.. that is a mistake..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many issues with your code.

- If you use `PaddingMode.None`, then you have to supply plaintext that is *exactly* a multiple of the block size (16 bytes for AES). So, you won't be able to simply encrypt arbitrary plaintexts. Please use `PaddingMode.Pkcs7` for encryption and decryption.
- You're reading the ciphertext before it is fully written. You need to call `encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();` *after* the `using (CryptoStream csEncrypt...` block:

  ```
  using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
  {
      using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
      {
          using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
          {
              swEncrypt.Write(toEncStr);
          }
      }
      encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
  }
  ```
- You have too many variables that could be used for encryption. You only need exactly one `Aes` instance (`enc`). Just throw away the code with `encaes` and `Program` and write the correct `Key` and `IV` from the `enc` instance.

---

The IV is not secret, so you can send it along with the ciphertext. Usually, it is simply prepended to the ciphertext and sliced off before decryption.

Comment: Thank you! I removed needless variables and changed `PaddingMode` to `PKCS7` and did like you said, it worked !

Comment: There happens another problem... When I put the decryption part of code `RunDecrypt` and `myDecrypt` to a solely decrypt program, there is an error saying `Decryption failed! Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.`  How come is this?

Comment: Another question, when I encrypted .zip or binary file, file size increased and files became corrupted. It seems that only txt file sizes can stay unchanged?

Comment: Invalid padding might mean you are not expecting the correct padding, or that there is another problem.